# Delete all scale animations from specific animation

Tags: animation

Is it possible to somehow delete all scale animations from a specific animation?
I am creating animations for unity, and in unity I get alot of warnings if I use scale animations, because they cost much performance.

Sometimes I accidentally add scale animations, then I have to find the specific bones and delete the scale animations on them one by one.

Is there a faster way, maybe a script?

Comment: In graph editor or dope sheet you can select all bones and type "scale" in search bar, then select all keyframes at once and delete.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Select all bones/objects
2. Open *Graph Editor* or *Dope Sheet*
3. Type "scale" in search bar
4. Select all keyframes and delete

[image]